# Why is a $C_{4}$-free regular graph such that a $2$-path exists between any pair of points always a triangle?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a simple graph, that is regular (the degree of every vertex is equal) and $C_{4}$-free (there are no squares in the graph), such that there exists a path with length $2$ between every pair of distinct vertices in $G$. I want to show that the only case this can hold is when $G$ is a triangle. 
An equivalent hypothesis is that $G$ is a simple regular graph such that there exists a unique path with length $2$ between every pair of distinct vertices in $G$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conditions of this problem (excluding regularity) are the same as those in the [friendship theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friendship_graph#Friendship_theorem). The result states a graph with diameter $2$ and no $C_4$ must be a a friendship graph.

The only regular friendship graph is the triangle.

Comment: Thank you bro! That really helped me out!

Comment: Glad to hear that !